# Transform this SQL query to LINQ to SQL

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
select aspnet_Users.UserName from aspnet_Users,aspnet_UsersInRoles, aspnet_Roles
where aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId=aspnet_Roles.RoleId
and
  aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId=aspnet_Users.UserId
and
  aspnet_Roles.RoleName='abc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from user in DbContext.Users
where user.UsersInRoles.Any(uir=>uir.Role.RoleName=="abc")
select user.UserName
```